# AWS Config is not appropriately enabled on some accounts alert in organizational securityhub (terraform)

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-hub

I have deployed security hub to a security account in aws. It shows as connecting to all accounts, but i get multiple errors for:

> AWS Config is not appropriately enabled on some accounts AWS Config is
> required for Security Hub's security checks. Review remediation steps
> for the related findings for CIS 2.5. If you recently enabled AWS
> Config, note that it can take up to 12 hours for Security Hub to
> detect the change.

In the root account i have `config.amazonaws.com`, `config-multiaccountsetup.amazonaws.com` and `securityhub.amazonaws.com` set for service_access

All examples ive seen for setting it up, dont need anything else, is there something im missing?

example post: https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-aws-securityhub-with-terraform-in-a-minute